# Serilog.Sink.Elasticsearch, Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api2, serilog, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Serilog and Serilog.Sink.Elasticsearch in an ASP web API project,
there is an issue with the connection to the ELK service that has been configured on an azure Kubernetes cluster, I get the error below when I deploy my code on the windows server 2012 R2, but it works on my desktop correctly, and SSL has been issued by LetsEncrypt and expiration time is fine

packages:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Elasticsearch.Net" version="7.17.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" version="8.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
```

error:

> 2022-04-06T11:49:33.7509141Z Caught exception while preforming bulk
> operation to Elasticsearch:
> Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The request was
> aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.. Call: Status code
> unknown from: POST /_bulk ---> System.Net.WebException: The request
> was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)
>
> at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
> requiresSynchronization)
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
>
> at
> Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.d__5`1.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
> Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.HandleElasticsearchClientException(RequestData
> data, Exception clientException, IElasticsearchResponse response)
>
> at
> Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.FinalizeResponse[TResponse](RequestData requestData, IRequestPipeline pipeline, List`1 seenExceptions,
> TResponse response)
>
> at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.<RequestAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
>
> at
> Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSink.d__2.MoveNext()

I've added these lines to Application_Start but it doesn't work me:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 went out of support a *long* time ago. It didn't support TLS1.2 without patching. The error is caused because Elastic requires *stronger* security (TLS1.2) not weaker. What you did was re-enable obsolete and insecure algorithms. To enable TLS1.2 on the server you'll have to patch it. Although it's high time that server was retired or upgraded

Comment: BTW identical questions have been asked a lot of times in the last 6+ years. By now all web and cloud providers require TLS1.2